# Using sln.DotSettings in TeamCity dotcover runner

Tags: nunit, teamcity, dotcover

I am using an NUnit 3 runner in a TeamCity 9.1.6 step. I've chosen "JetBrains dotCover" as the .NET Coverage tool, and now I'd like this step to use the xxx.sln.DotSettings file that we've put in source control and that we're sharing across devs in Visual Studio, rather than to duplicate settings to TeamCity Filters, Attribute Filters etc. Is this possible in TeamCity?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible from the box now. It is a great idea, could you create an issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

But there is a simple workaround:

- you could parse dotSettins manually on the first step
- publish configuration parameters using ##teamcity[setParameter name='ddd' value='fff'] TeamCity service message (see for details https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity)
- use those configuration parameters in the appropriate fields for dotCover like %ddd%

Comment: I was hoping I could at least pass the sln.DotSettings file as an argument to the dotCover exe in TeamCity? No luck there either?